# Android System Trace [trace markers]

Tags: android, user-interface, systrace

I'm trying to make RecyclerView scroll smoothly. Starting with analyzing traces from Android Device Monitor > DDMS > Android Systrace I thought that adding custom sections could be helpful. Here, you can find example I use to accomplish this. Could someone please point me where can find section logs I added? Thanks.

```
@Override
public CalendarMatchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //        calendar_match_item  calendar_match_item
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        Trace.beginSection("onCreateViewHolder");
    }
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_match_item, parent, false);
    CalendarMatchViewHolder vh = new CalendarMatchViewHolder(view);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        Trace.endSection();
    }
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CalendarMatchViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Match match = mMatches.get(position);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        Trace.beginSection("onBindViewHolder");
    }
    setOtherMatchesBasicData(match, holder);
    setOfferLayout(match, holder);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        Trace.endSection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by selecting package name in Systrace window from drop down menu "Enter Application Traces From".

You can find more about Systrace and how to use it on this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace.html

[image: Systrace window]

Answer (score 1):

Android Profiler can be used. Just a Note : You need to be looking for Janky Frames if you are dealing with performance issues / rendering issues.

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/jank-detection

Another Useful Link

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render